# How to reduce MySQL replication delay

Tags: mysql, replication

I have two MySQL Enterprise servers for master host and slave host. Replication has been setup successfully and works grate.

One day I have to kill query from master and then stop the slave. Then I had skip counter + 1 relay log and start slave again.

Then replication is not done real time and there is a time gap between master and slave.

Seconds_Behind_Master = 12222

How can I reduce this delay.

[image: SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G]

Comment: Normally a delay of this size means one of:- a: The slave is vastly underpowered and cannot keep up with the live or more likely b: It encountered a query it couldn't replicate and stopped processing some time ago and it had not been noticed that the time behind master was going up.

Comment: @Anigel Can I reduce this gap using any method

Comment: Depends on the reason. if its a. Upgrade your slave server. If its b. monitor that number and act as soon as it starts going up. If its something else then the action to take depends on knowing what the cause is.

Comment: @Anigel How can I update slave?

Is there any command?

Comment: upgrade - or make more powerful, there is no command that will make the server higher powered. Find out what the actual cause is and then you can ask a question saying how do I fix a specific problem. There are too many possible causes and solutions from the information you have given.